# Booting screen is showing different loading screen instead of ubuntu and lock screen isn't coming [19.10]

Tags: boot, 19.10, lock-screen

After this boot/splash screen, system bypasses the lock screen (lock screen doesn't comes) to desktop.
Help please.

[image: boot-screen that's coming instead of purple Ubuntu screen]

Comment: You might have opted for auto login option..

Comment: how to check it? and what about the booting screen?

Comment: When you logged in check in user accounts.. There is a switch for auto login.. Turn it off.. For boot-screen you might have installed other packages which automatically customised/ selected this new boot screen.. You have to select the default boot screen..

Comment: Thanks for help, It's solved now. I got to know a lot plymouth and other settings.

Comment: update-alternatives command will do..